# get_the_category_list open in parent window

Tags: categories, iframe

I'm opening my posts in an iframe, and I'm using `get_the_category_list` to list post's categories. The problem is that when a user clicks on the category link, it opens in the iframe. How can I set the target for these generated links to be "_parent"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_the_category_list`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list) runs it output through the filter `the_category`.  You could hook in there and change whatever you like.  Something like this should work (untested):

```
<?php
add_filter('the_category', 'wpse90955_the_category');
function wpse90955_the_category($cat_list)
{
    return str_ireplace('<a', '<a target="_parent"', $cat_list);
}
```

If you just need to have that list filter in certain spots, you can define the function above in a plugin or theme's `functions.php`, then add the filter, call `get_the_category_list`, and remove the filter.

```
<?php
// assume wpse90955_the_category was defined elsewhere and is already loaded
add_filter('the_category', 'wpse90955_the_category');
echo get_the_category_list($some_sep, $parents, $some_post_id);
remove_filter('the_category', 'wpse90955_the_category');
```